# Finding the lebesgue decomposition of a piecewise continuous function $F(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, radon-nikodym

Define $F(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & x < -1 \\
          x + 2 & -1\leq x < 0 \\
          x^2 + 3 & 0\leq x < 1\\
          6   & x \ge 1
       \end{cases}$

I want to find the Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu_F$ (w.r.t Lebesgue measure), the Lebesgue-Stieljes measure associated with the function $F$, and then find the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the absolutely continuous part of the decomposition.

I note that $\mu_{F1 + F2} = \mu_{F1} + \mu_{F2}$, so I try to decompose $F$ itself as the sum of a continuous function and something else:

$F = G + H$ where

$G(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & x < -1 \\
          x + 1 & -1\leq x < 0 \\
          x^2 + 1 & 0\leq x < 1\\
          2   & x \ge 1
       \end{cases}$

$H(x) =  \begin{cases} 
          0 & x < -1 \\
          1 & -1\leq x < 0 \\
          2 & 0\leq x < 1\\
          4   & x \ge 1
       \end{cases}$

My question is then what would $\mu_H$ be? My intuition tells me it is equal to $\delta_{-1} + 2\delta_{0} + 4\delta_{1}$, but I am not able to prove this. If I have this, I can then prove $\mu_H, \mu$ are mutually singular by decomposing into $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ and the rest of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, I am not sure how to find the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu_G$. I think I can just take the regular derivative of $F$, but I am unsure as to why it is the same thing.